# Is there any way to make a hook while debugging in gdb & gdbserver?

Tags: c++, linux, gdb, gdbserver

There is a huge project (under Linux) which consists of dozens of executables. Mainly, all of them are written in C++. The project is designed in such a way that the `main` function and the events handling cycle is more or less similar in all of this executables. And one of details of this handling cycle is that there is a checking of existence of certain file in it. If this file exists then main working code is skipped and the `sleep` function is simply called. So, I can "pause" all executables in the project via creating of this file and "resume" them via deleting of this file, though theirs execution will not be actually interrupted in a physical meaning. This is a convenient feature when I need to perform some debugging tasks.

Now, the question: is there any way to create this pause-file automatically when execution of some of the project's programs is trapped by a break-point set by the `gdb` and delete it when execution is continued? Debugging is fulfilled using the `gdbserver` (remotely).

Comment: The answer to half of your question is, yes, [there are hooks](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Hooks.html). But to create and remove a file using gdb commands, we'd need to know more about how this file is created and removed. Gdb can call a function in the stopped program, and it can run shell commands.